# JavaFX - switch stages and setX and setY of new stage

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am familiarizing with JavaFX. I have created a loginStage and a mainStage. When pressing the 'Login' Button on the loginStage, I want to switch to the mainStage. The loginStage is a lot smaller than the mainStage. I want the mainStage to be located such that the former loginStage was positioned right in the middle of the mainStage (if we hadn't closed it).

I managed to switch from the loginStage to the mainStage. But for some reason the mainStage does not position itself correctly; it seems to me that its X- and Y-coordinate are not set at all!

Here is my code:

```
 public void switchWindow() {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        try {
            Stage loginStage = (Stage) btnLogin.getScene().getWindow();
            loginStage.setScene(null);
            loginStage.hide();

            Pane mainPane= (Pane) loader.load(getClass().getResource("/mainStage.fxml"));
            Stage mainStage= new Stage();
            mainStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
            Scene mainScene= new Scene(mainPane);
            mainStage.setScene(mainScene);

            mainStage.setX(loginStage.getX() + loginStage.getWidth()/2 - mainStage.getWidth()/2);
            mainStage.setY(loginStage.getY() + loginStage.getHeight()/2 - mainStage.getHeight()/2);

            mainStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Also: I will be creating more stages. Hence, I figured it might be a good idea to create a `switchWindow()` function inside a separate package. I might just call the function with parameters `oldStage and newPane`. I wanted to ask you: What is the best practice of switching between stages? So that I do not reproduce the same code over and over again?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - and yes, I am sorry, this seems to have been answered before.

The problem is that `.getWidth()` or `.getHeight()` methods can only be invoked AFTER the `.show()` method. Therefore, either change the order of calling the functions. This works fine - the mainStage seems to be at the correct x,y-coordinates from begin on. But to be sure that it does not get moved there after showing the stage, we could also just look up the width and the height of the mainStage inside the .fxml file and then substract these values in `.setX()` and `.setY()` respectively.